# CSS selectors for first occurrence of class contained in another class

Tags: css-selectors

I want to access the first element with class=x contained in class y.
I have this as my selector '.x .y'
But this selects all elements with class y contained in class x. I just want the first. How can I do that with selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```css
.x .y:first-of-type{
  /* Your CSS code here */ 
}
```

Comment: I'm webscraping so I'm trying to use the right selector. If I do Ctrl+F after inspecting. I can put a css selector or xpath expression. If I do '.x .y:first-of-type', nothing comes up.
When I do just '.x .y' two elements are highlighted on the page.

Comment: You should be more clear about that in your question. The only other recommendation is something like `.x .y:nth-child(n)`, where `n` is the specific element you want to access.